# How do I set permissions to a Zeppelin Note to be able to execute but not change the code and configuration?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

How do I set permissions to a Zeppelin Note to do only the following :

1. execute the paragraphs
2. choose a different value from dynamic dropdown
3. change display type from bar chart to tabular ...
4. download the result data as a csv or tsv file

I do not want the users to change the code or access Interpreter menu or change configuration.

Thanks

-Anna

Comment: I want the same. You can change the permissions each notebook if you have enabled "shiro" authentification (https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/security/shiroauthentication.html) to a user with only reader privileges. But there are downsides: 1. the user can still access the "Interpreters" with database credentials and 2. the user cannot execute the notebook so he only sees the last run of an "owner" or "writer" (see https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/80902/how-does-the-zeppelin-notebook-permissions-work.html).

Comment: A PR was just submitted. https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2526